# Counting files in a folder with JS

Tags: javascript, html, file, count, directory

How can I count the nº of files in a folder with JavaScript?

With PHP I can do it, but not with JS.

I'm trying to use only JS because it's going to be on a USB drive for simple access (something simple to use).

```php
$i = 0;
$dir = 'pics/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir . $file))
      $i++;
    }
   }
echo "$i";
```

This is what I was using with PHP, but in my USB drive the best to use is HTML for simpler access.

Comment: You cant read files from your computer with js. Only if you using server lang on the server side. Or you should download files by yourself. For example `<input type='file'>`

Comment: But you can install server on your computer for example nodejs

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have the access to the file system. You can use server side JavaScript like, Node.js to access the file system.

Comment: In the browser you can't, yet (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API). You need to use something like nodejs. You can create an executable from it with e.g. nexe/nexe or vercel/pkg. Have fun hacking. You can do it! 

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './folder';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```